# How do I create a 'All' filter button to filter my products in React?

Tags: reactjs, button, filter

How do I create a 'All' filter button to filter my products? As you can see Ive got the filter buttons for each category but nothing seems to work for 'all'. I think its something simple that Ive missed but cant work it out. Im new to coding so its all a learning curve at the moment  thanks in advance

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const HOME_GARDEN = 'home and garden';
const ART = 'Art';


export default function Shop({ setCart, cart, handleClick }) {
const [products] = useState([
{
    category: ART,
    name: 'Original David Bowie Mug Shot Mixed Media Framed Artwork',
    cost: 200,
    image:'images/bowie.jpeg',
    page:'Bowie',
    description: "Original David Bowie Mug Shot Mixed Media Framed Artwork floral 
painting on wooden canvas with an original pop art style David Bowie Mugshot on top 
painting is framed with a red baroque style frame including the words deadly flowers 
 bloom around frame",

  },

{
    category: HOME_GARDEN,
    name: 'Blanket',
    cost: 19.99,
    image:
    'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcSpwdYDmUL_ZEqhLV7ZWRdQAU7DGcGaxtCt7SrTlL9umrQs2Un7rj9Nbb9Vq01RtEfA0eAVmdt-&usqp=CAc',
    page:'Blanket',


    },
  ]);

 const addToCart = (product) => {
let newCart = [...cart];
let itemInCart = newCart.find(
  (item) => product.name === item.name
);
if (itemInCart) {
  itemInCart.quantity++;
} else {
  itemInCart = {
    ...product,
    quantity: 1,
  };
  newCart.push(itemInCart);
}
setCart(newCart);
```

};

```
const [category, setCategory] = useState(HOME_GARDEN);

const getProductsInCategory = () => {
return products.filter(
(product) => product.category === category
 );
 };
```

return (
<>

## Shop

```
    <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(ART)}>
      Art</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory(HOME_GARDEN)}>
        Home and Garden</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => setCategory()}>
          All</button>
  <div className="products">
      {getProductsInCategory().map((product, idx) =>(
        <div className="product" key={idx}>
          <h3>{product.name}</h3>
          <h4>£{product.cost}</h4>
          <img src={product.image} alt={product.name} />
          <br />
          <button onClick={() => addToCart(product)}>
            Add to Cart
          </button>

          <button onClick={() => handleClick(product)}>
              View Product
            </button>
        </div>
    ))}
```

```
</>
```

);
}

Comment: So, if category is `undefined` you want to show all the products? To do that, add a line at the beginning of `getProductsInCategory` that says `if (category === undefined) return products`

Comment: I think this is where Im getting the issue as each category is defined and Im not sure how to define 2 categories e.g. 'Art' and 'All'  for the art category

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Potentially this:

```
const getProductsInCategory = () => {
    if (category === ALL) {
        return products;
    } else {
        return products.filter((product) => product.category === category);
    }
};
```

Add an 'all' category at the top:

```
const HOME_GARDEN = 'home and garden';
const ART = 'Art'; 
const ALL = 'All';
```

On your 'All' button, use:

```
<button onClick={(e) => setCategory(ALL)}>
          All</button>
```

Comment: ok, if I include that do I remove the getproductsincategory  and how do I define ALL at the top? Thanks

Comment: you could define it as you have with the other categories, at the top like 'const ALL = "ALL"'. then set the category with your onClick method for your All button

Comment: I've modified my answer to better show this.

Comment: Ok, Im now getting a message about getproductsincategory is not defined. How do I change that part to (just below the button). Thanks

Comment: are you still using the getproductsincategory method? you will need to format it as 'const getProductsInCategory = () => {
if (category === ALL) {
    return products;
} else {
    return products.filter((product) => product.category === category);
}
 };'